# $o$-notation appearing in inequality

Tags: inequality, notation, asymptotics

I only know the $o$-notation in terms of equalities, but I've never seen it appearing in an inequality. Could anybody explain to me what is stated here?

$$f(k) \le k^22^k(\ln2)(1+o(1))$$

For context, the inequality appears in *The probabilistic method* on page 4. The book can be found here:

http://nguyen.hong.hai.free.fr/EBOOKS/SCIENCE%20AND%20ENGINEERING/MATHEMATIQUE/PROBABILITY/The_Probabilistic_Method.pdf

Comment: I would guess that $o(1)$ is meant to be a positive function that goes to zero as $k$ is made larger. Does that make sense in the context in which you saw it?

Comment: I honestly cannot tell, but I gave some context above.

Comment: They mean $f(k) \leq g(k)$, where $g(k) = k^2 2^k (\ln 2)(1+o(1))$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(k) = o(g(k))$ means that as $k \to \infty$ for every positive constant $\varepsilon$ there exists a constant $K$ such that

$$
|f(k)|\leq \varepsilon |g(k)|\qquad {\text{for all }}k\geq K~.
$$

So, if a function $h(k)$ is $o(1)$ it means that as $k \to \infty$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$

$$
|h(k)| \leq \varepsilon \qquad {\text{for all }}k\geq K~.
$$

In the inequality you're asking about:

$$
f(k) \leq k^22^k(\ln2)(1 + o(1))
$$

the author means that as $k$ gets "large" $f$ is bounded by $k^22^k(\ln2)$ plus a "very small" multiple of the same.